# Patch SUPEE 11086 Hunk #1 FAILED at 144

Tags: magento-1.7, error, patches

I want to apply the patch SUPEE 11086 on magento 1.7 store but it gives me the following error:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 804.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/Buttons.php

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Buttons.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Store/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 403 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Email/PathValidator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Gatewayurl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Protected.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Api/RoleController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Api/UserController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/Action/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/DesignController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Block/Adminhtml/Roles/Buttons.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/RoleController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/StreamWrapper.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 757 (offset -21 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/ConsumerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/Widget/InstanceController.php
checking file app/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 144.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 100 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 110 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Rss.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Widget.csv
checking file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
checking file lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hunk #1 FAILED at 144** means line does not match to the patch. Definitely modified those file that is why refusing to apply the patch.

**The easy solution is:** copy affected file from the core(that magento offer, download from magento) replace this and try to apply the patch again.